# How to install SOAUI open source tool?

Tags: soapui

Can anyone please tell me how to install SOAPUI. I download SoapUI 5.0.0 from soapui.org, But it is asking for license key to open.

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI installation is covered on their website, here: http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/installing-on-windows.html

SoapUI comes in two "flavours": the -Pro and open-source. See this: http://www.soapui.org/Go-Pro/compare-soapui-and-soapui-pro.html The -Pro version is licensed. You are able to cancel the license prompt, at which point you will begin a trial period.